# Can we attach a SQL Server database with more than 1 mdf file?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a parent database and I'm planning to split them out into subsets like below.

When generating the subsets, each DB will have their own `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

If I have to attach both `DBAlpha` and `DBBeta` on same setup, how can I merge both `.mdf` files and create a single database out of it?

Does below script work to create a DB with 2 `.mdf` files?

MasterDB -> DBAlpha, DBBeta, DBGama

```
CREATE DATABASE [NewDBAlphaBeta] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQL\SQLData\DBAlpha.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQL\SQLLog\DBBeta.mdf' )
FOR ATTACH
```

Comment: FYI the "master" database is a specific thing in SQL Server, it's a system database, so stating you have a "master database" is a bit confusing as *everyone does*.

Comment: Although SQL Server will let you use whatever file extensions you choose, each database should have exactly one mdf file (the primary data file). All other data files should have extension ndf (secondary data file). Log files should have extension ldf. The `CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH` is very confusing since the `SQLLog` directory name suggests it's a log file, not data file, and should thus have an ldf extension.

Comment: If those are really two databases, you would use two `create database` statements.

Comment: You cannot attach data files from different databases to form a single database.

Comment: @ThomA, I have updated the master keyword to parent to avoid confusion.

Comment: The database name would be same. If I need to merge alpha and beta DBs, result would be "RandomDBName" with both the DB objects from alpha and beta mdf files.

Comment: Your question makes no sense given the way SQL Server works. *"I have a parent database and I'm planning to split them out into subsets like below. When generating the subsets, each DB will have their own .mdf and .ldf files."* doesn't really make sense. You can make different databases by copying the data but then they don't function as a unit, or you can make different files for the MDF, but the log files are split in a different way (if at all). *"If I have to attach both DBAlpha and DBBeta on same setup, how can I merge both .mdf files and create a single database out of it?"* I thought...

Comment: ... you said you want to split them, not merge them? *"Does below script work to create a DB with 2 .mdf files?"* now I'm really confused, it sounded like you had a single database you wanted to split, now seem to say you have two files which were once part of a single database and you want to attach them (where is the LDF file), in this case it's one database with two files, not two databases, except you are missing the LDF log file. So what's *really* going on? What is your current setup, how many databases and how many files do you have, where are these files from? ....

Comment: .... what are you *actually* trying to do? If you want to move a database, why aren't you using `BACKUP` `RESTORE`?

Comment: Its kind of split and merge. I have a usecase where I need to create subsets of a DB.
ParentDB would be a super set DB and its subsets would be DBAlpha, DBBeta, DBGamma. In some scenarios, both DBAlpha and DBBeta can be used on same setup. In some scenarios, only one subset is required.

When only one subset is required, we are good with one subset. but when more than 1 subset is required for a use case, how can we create a union of the subsets?

Comment: That doesn't really help me. How do you propose to split this database? You can't just split a database, you'd need to copy the data to a new one. What do you want as the end result? A single database? Multiple? Single with multiple files? Please be clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the logicals objets of two different databases (tables, views, sql schema, procedures, functions...) you have to do it logically by creating each object from secondary database into the first database, then migrates all data from the secondary to the first. There is no way to do this physically by the bias of files, because file does contains only binaries entries like exe code from an application program...

To have the DDL of all objects and the data to inserts use the wizard.